# html5 data attributes from an active class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to get the html5 data-sku="002" from an element with a class of selected.

Ideally would like to set a variable if the data-sku="002" and has a class of selected. Then I could use if/else or show()/hide() to enable or disable other elements on my page later on.

```
<li data-sku="002" data-id="1590" data-price="120"
data-label="You have selected: Premium" class="selected">
    <span class="price"><sup>€</sup>120</span>
        <span class="title-plan">Premium
            <span><p>Premium Package</p>
            </span>
        </span>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-submit-price-plan select-plan">Select</a>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</li>
```

I have made a example on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gkrrbnyy/2/
But I am shooting in the dark a bit.

Any ideas on the best way to approach this? As I am not very experienced with jquery.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. In the end I have taken all on board and made a few changes - see http://jsfiddle.net/gkrrbnyy/6/ for more. Added a delay function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `jQuery(".selected[data-sku=002]").text()` for `jQuery(".selected").find('[data-sku=002]').text()` ; `.selected` has `data-*` attribute , not `.selected` child nodes , which `.find()` traverses

http://jsfiddle.net/gkrrbnyy/4/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want:

`jQuery('.selected').data('sku')`

for example:

```
jQuery(".select-plan").click(function(){
    alert('Selectecd sku is: '+jQuery('.selected').data('sku'));
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbhsnqeg/1/ (updated)

And here why: https://api.jquery.com/data/

You could also use `jQuery(".select-plan").attr('data-sku')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
$(".select-plan").click(function() {
  // gives the element that has class=selected and data-sku='002'   
  temp = $(".selected[data-sku=002]") 
    //$(temp).data('sku') gives the value of the element's attribute 
    //data-sku
  $("#myID").html($(temp).data('sku')); 
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crp7jqzd/)

Answer (score 0):

Selector `.selected[data-sku=002]` can be used for finding the element which has both.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gkrrbnyy/3/)

```
jQuery(".select-plan").click(function(){
    mfvariable = jQuery(".selected[data-sku=002]").length;
    if( mfvariable > 0 )
        alert('Exists');
    else
        alert('Not found');
});
```